# Function in Google Big Query

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to create a function in google biq query, but i m getting the below error. any help is appreciated:

```
CREATE FUNCTION `test.xx.x_to_y_Id`(ID INT64)
RETURNS INT64

    SELECT CASE 
  WHEN CAST(FLOOR(ID/POWER(CAST(2 AS INT64),38)) AS INT64) & 3 = 0
    THEN ID & CAST(12345678 AS INT64)
    ELSE ID END

Syntax error: Expected "(" or string literal but got keyword SELECT at [4:9]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this as the CREATE function statement

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION
  test(ID FLOAT64) 
AS ( 
CASE 
WHEN CAST(FLOOR(ID/POWER(CAST(2 AS INT64),38)) AS INT64) & 3 = 0
  THEN ID & CAST(12345678 AS INT64)
ELSE ID END);
```

Note: I removed the `SELECT` from the body of the function and corrected the function signature to match BigQuery function style as defined [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions)

Comment: @Anusha note: important on SO - you can mark accepted answer by using the tick on the left of the posted answer, below the voting. See [meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#5235)… for why it is important

Answer (score 1):

Below is fixed version of your function

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION test(ID INT64)
RETURNS INT64 AS ((
  SELECT CASE 
    WHEN CAST(FLOOR(ID/POWER(CAST(2 AS INT64),38)) AS INT64) & 3 = 0
    THEN ID & CAST(12345678 AS INT64)
    ELSE ID 
  END
));
SELECT test(12)
```

As you can see - you were missing some aspects of it like `TEMP` keyword, some open and close brackets, etc.

Meantime, as in simple scenario like yours - you can omit use of `SELECT` and just use expression alone like in below example (note in this case you also getting rid of extra open/close brackets

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION test(ID INT64)
RETURNS INT64 AS (
  CASE 
    WHEN CAST(FLOOR(ID/POWER(CAST(2 AS INT64),38)) AS INT64) & 3 = 0
    THEN ID & CAST(12345678 AS INT64)
    ELSE ID 
  END
);
SELECT test(12)
```